# Styling HR elements with bootstrap/CSS

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I'm currently implementing bootstrap into my portfolio website and I cannot style the hr elements at all, they constantly come out looking like this:

[image]

It also aligns to the left constantly, I cannot center them at all. No clue what's the issue, when I was only using CSS/HTML, it was fine and looked like this:

[image]

CSS code from original project before bootstrap:

```
hr{
  border-color: #1b1b1b;
  width: 50px;
  border-style: dotted none none;
  border-width: 8px;
}
```

This didn't work putting into my CSS file I'm using for the site with bootstrap, so I tried this:

```
.hr-styled{
  border:none;
  border-top: 15px dotted #999;
  width: 30%;
  border-color: #1b1b1b;
}
```

I get what's shown in the first image, if I remove #999 I get no dots at all.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: take a look at the devtools on the browser, it could be that bootstrap it's applying a reset or bootstrap it's being loaded after your custom stylesheet

Answer (score 0):

Which version of bootstrap are you using?
Remeber to bind your custom CSS right AFTER the bootstrap.css, to avoid issues and overrides.

Add the class `text-center` on the parent div, to center the full content inside.

If its now working, please set up an [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) and i will check it up.

Comment: Hello, It's bootstrap 5 and I have been adding the CSS file after the bootstrap link.